# Change language in Android App

Tags: android, locale

I want to change the language in my app programatically.
The first onCreate(Bundle) method works and the images are displayed in chinese.
The second doesnt work. What do I have to insert in the "TODO" comment? I want to change the language AFTER the view was created and want to update it.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TranslationHelper.changeLanguage(this, Locale.CHINESE);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    doBindService();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    TranslationHelper.changeLanguage(this, Locale.CHINESE);
    // TODO recreate view to display chinese version
    doBindService();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sample works because it changes locale before `setContentView` method is called. You need to insert `changeLanguage` before `setContentView`. 
All views are already inflated after `setContentView` so changing locale at this point will have no effect. You need to update it manually if you want to change the language after the view was created.

Comment: If you are changing locale in `Resources` class then `Context.getString` should return texts in new locale after that, Chinese in your case. So you need to set text for all `TextView` entities manually. There is no way to do this at once without recreating view hierarchy. And btw why you can't just change you locale before calling `setContentView`? It will be definitely more simple.

Comment: i cant because when the user presses the back button the view wont be recreated and the old language will be displayed

Comment: If you want to change language on the previous activity you can call `setContentView` again in `onActivityResult` for example.